# Impersonization fails in a web application when accessed from remote computer

Tags: asp.net, impersonation, identity-delegation

I have a web application which is configured to run under NTLM scheme. 
From the web application I am accessing a service in application server. 
I am impersonating the user in the web application code which accesses the service in application server.
When I access the web application from the web server everything works fine.
But when I try to access the web application from a different client machine with same credentials the the call to service in application server is failing with access denied.
The same scenario is working in different set of machines.
Am I missing any settings?

Answer (score 0):

If we setup the delegation from the app pool identity account in ADC and choose “any protocol” instead of  "Kerberos only" the problem is getting resolved.